# Oracle 12.2 Breaks on Install on Windows 10 Pro machine

Tags: windows, oracle-12c

I am coming from a Linux background, so I don't know much about Windows at all.

I have a factory fresh Windows 10 Pro machine and I have anti-virus and firewall disabled.

I downloaded the 12.2c software and extracted it and then ran the setup file. The installer gets to the portion where it is trying to check prerequisites -- it gets to about 85% and then just closes on its own.

This is so extremely frustrating and I don't see anything in the install log that indicates any issue. I've attached the last few lines of the log file here:

```
INFO: CVU tracingEnabled = false
INFO: Nodes are prepared for verification.
INFO: Completed executing action at state <performChecks>
INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations
INFO: Finishing all forked tasks at state performChecks
INFO: Waiting for completion all forked tasks at state performChecks
INFO: Creating PrereqChecker Job for leaf task Physical Memory
INFO: Creating PrereqChecker Job for leaf task Available Physical Memory
INFO: Creating PrereqChecker Job for leaf task Swap Size
INFO: Creating CompositePrereqChecker Job for container task Free Space
INFO: Creating PrereqChecker Job for leaf task Free Space: laptop-8gmvgrg9:C:\Users\shopp\AppData\Local\Temp
INFO: Creating PrereqChecker Job for leaf task Architecture
INFO: Creating PrereqChecker Job for leaf task Environment variable: "PATH"
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Physical Memory: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the system has at least 1GB (1048576.0KB) of total physical memory.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:1GB (1048576.0KB)
INFO: Actual Value:15.8406GB (1.661008E7KB)
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Available Physical Memory: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the system has at least 50MB (51200.0KB) of available physical memory.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:50MB (51200.0KB)
INFO: Actual Value:13.0944GB (1.3730516E7KB)
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Swap Size: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether sufficient total swap space is available on the system.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:15.8406GB (1.661008E7KB)
INFO: Actual Value:18.7156GB (1.9624736E7KB)
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Free Space: laptop-8gmvgrg9:C:\Users\shopp\AppData\Local\Temp: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether sufficient free space is available in the file system.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:500MB 
INFO: Actual Value:400.8525GB 
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: *********************************************
INFO: Architecture: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the system has a certified architecture.
INFO: Severity:CRITICAL
INFO: OverallStatus:SUCCESSFUL
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:laptop-8gmvgrg9
INFO: Expected Value:64-bit
INFO: Actual Value:64-bit
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried installing it as Admin, rather than a user? Think *sudo*.

Comment: I ran it with "Run as administrator" option

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same ending lines in the install log. My computer is almost new but i had installed a few products before Oracle database 12.2, among others:
- Oracle database 12.1 64 bits
- Oracle client 12.2 32 bits
- ODTwithODAC122010 (to use Visual Studio on Oracle)
Did you install any of this Softwares on your computer before trying to install Oracle database 12.2 64 bits ?

Comment: No, I tried installing Oracle after a clean restore of Windows 10 Pro. Eventually I got it working -- I had to do clean restore, then install all Windows updates, then stop all 'startup' services, and stop all non-Microsoft services. Then I disabled anti-virus and Windows defender and was finally able to get a successful installation.

Answer (score -1):

No, I tried installing Oracle after a clean restore of Windows 10 Pro. Eventually I got it working -- I had to do clean restore, then install all Windows updates, then stop all 'startup' services, and stop all non-Microsoft services. Then I disabled anti-virus and Windows defender and was finally able to get a successful installation.